# MySQL on duplicate key update without updating the recorded row

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I read about the MySQL command `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. I have a column `Surnames` in a `Users` table. Since there must be no identical `surnames`, I want to INSERT a new `surname` when the `surname` isn't in the database, and leave the row as it was recorded if the `surname` was previously saved in the database, without updating it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT IGNORE ...` will try to insert a new row, if a duplicate key is found the new data will be discarded.

[Documentation of `INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)